# Subsetting two factors in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a huge dataset, and I have a column called season. There are 4 seasons i.e. Winter, Spring, Summer and Autumn.

```
Region  Year    Male    Female  Area    DATE    Day Month   Season
WEST    1996    0   1   4   06-04-96    Saturday    April   Spring
EAST    1996    0   1   16  29-06-96    Saturday    June    Summer
WEST    1996    0   1   4   19-10-96    Saturday    October Winter
WEST    1996    0   1   4   20-10-96    Sunday  October Winter
EAST    1996    0   1   16  01-11-96    Friday  November    Winter
EAST    1996    0   1   16  11-11-96    Monday  November    Winter
WEST    1996    0   1   4   19-11-96    Tuesday November    Winter
WEST    1996    0   1   4   28-11-96    Thursday    November    Winter
WEST    1996    0   1   4   10-12-96    Tuesday December    Winter
WEST    1997    0   1   4   17-01-97    Friday  January Winter
WEST    1997    0   1   4   28-03-97    Friday  March   Spring
```

So I am trying to create a subset where I want R to show me entries with season as Winter and Autumn.

I created a subset first of the portion I want.

```
secondphase<-subset(eb1, Area>16)
```

now from this subset, I want where Season is Winter and Autumn.

I tried these codes-

```
th2<-subset(secondphase, Season== "Winter")
th3<-subset(secondphase, Season=="Autumn")
```

Now is there a way to merge these two subsets? or create a subset where I can select the conditions where I want area>16, season should be Winter and autumn.

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Try: th2<-subset(secondphase, Season== "Winter" | Season=="Autumn") where | means logical OR

Comment: Read this (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).

Comment: The edit you just made ruined all of the formatting... I rolled it back but let me know if you need help. I think you were trying to do codeblock formatting yourself but you used the wrong type of tick marks. Also that won't work for multi-line code like the table -- you have to use the codeblock feature.

Comment: @Dave2e Or skip the first step and just do `final <-subset(eb1[eb1$Area > 16,], Season== "Winter" | Season=="Autumn")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
my_subset <- eb1[eb1$Season %in% c("Winter", "Autumn") & eb1$Area > 16,]
```

**Method 2**

```
th2   <- subset(secondphase, Season== "Winter")
th3   <- subset(secondphase, Season=="Autumn")
final <- rbind(th2, th3)
```

**Method 3**

```
final <-subset(eb1[eb1$Area > 16,], Season== "Winter" | Season=="Autumn")
```

Comment: Thank a lot, you are amazin!

Comment: @SrivatsChari Happy to help!

Comment: I had another problem with linear regression model if you can help me out. @Hack-R

Comment: @SrivatsChari Did you open another question for it? What's the problem?

Comment: I cant open another question for like 90 mins :P is there a way I can ask you this question? Through email or something? Or should I wait for 90 mins? @Hack-R.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @Hack-R

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the dplyr package with the filter function

```
filter(secondphase, grepl("Winter|Autumn", Season))
```

Comment: Your syntax is not quite right; you can't use `|` within a string outside of regex patterns, or `==` will try to match it literally. You need either `eb1 %>% filter(Area > 16, Season == 'Winter' | Season == 'Autumn')` or `eb1 %>% filter(Area > 16, Season %in% c('Winter', 'Autumn'))`

Answer (score 0):

With a `data.table` approach,

```
library("data.table")
DT<-data.table(eb1)
subsetDT<-subset(DT, Season %in% c("Autmn","Winter") & Area > 16)
```

does the job.